# How to fully automatically bootstrap Jenkins for Maven jobs in git?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

We have plenty Maven modules spread over several branches in several git repositories, and we have found the manual configuration of Jenkins for each of these jobs to be tedious and error prone.

Hence I am looking at how to automate our Jenkins installation, and in order to make it reproducible, I want to start with the unconfigured WAR as downloaded from the Jenkins site, get the necessary configuration done, and then create jobs based on descriptions from a suitable Domain Specific Language.  This process needs to be fully automated and robust, preferably through the CLI jar.

So far I have hit the following issues:

- Jenkins does not know about Maven versions or have Git Client installed out-of-the-box.
- The knowledge is downloaded from the update site, which is triggered by Javascript in the browser when going to the `/manage` site.  Then I can install the git plugin from the update center.
- Configuring "I want maven 3.0.4 and just download it" needs to be done through the configuration web page.  I have not found a suitable CLI command to do the same.

After doing so manually, I could use the CLI create-job command with a suitable XML configuration file to do the rest of what I need.

So, how can I automate these steps?  Not having to orchestrate a Javascript capable browser would be nice.  Platform is a headless Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

For creating the jobs using a DSL, take a look at the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin).  You could trigger the execution of the seed job that creates the build jobs via the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is each of the plugins on jenkins-ci.org has a "latest" symlink:

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/git.hpi , the "latest" jenkins war and the latest maven plugin can be downloaded easily.

- Create a directory for JENKINS_HOME, add various plugins straight from updates center into the a created plugins dir.
- Add conf.xml files straight to setup default JDK/MAVEN versions
- Start jenkins with JENKINS_HOME variable set

Our company workflow for setting up Jenkins uses Capistrano to install Java, Ruby, Tomcat and jenkins.war, a bunch of required plugins and an Apache vhost proxy in front of Jenkins. It is easily a Chef recipe, but quite doable without ruby.